# Unable to reference style and font resources in xml from library module

Tags: android, xml, fonts, dependencies, shared-libraries

The localization_lib library module's localized string and drawable resources are indeed used (such as values-ar). But in my app module style.xml I am unable to reference a custom style or font from the library.
I have tried:

```
<style name="PromoTextFontLocalized" parent="PromoTextFont">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/arial</item>
</style>
```

As well as using the package name:

```
 <style name="PromoTextFontLocalized" parent="PromoTextFont">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@com.example.localization_lib:font/alef_bold</item>
</style>
```

I also tried pointing directly to the library's source set in my gradle file:

```
 sourceSets {
    lite {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/lite/res', 'localization_lib/src/lite/res']
    }

}
```